# How to loop through values in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I want to change the mean, lambda, of a poisson process every time ticks advance by one.

Let's say lambda is a predetermined list of the following numbers: [1 2 3 4 5].

If I define lambda in this way, is it possible for NetLogo to loop through each position of the list based on the time step? E.g., at the first tick, NetLogo will set lambda to equal to the first item of the list, such that lambda = 1, when tick = 2, lambda = 2, etc.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
to recruit-spores

  ask turtles with [color = red] [

    hatch-spores random-poisson lambda ; lambda is what I want to change at every tick

      [set shape "dot"
       set size 0.01
       set color orange
       setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]

    ] 

end
```

Is there a way to change the value of lambda by looping through a list in NetLogo? Either through NetLogo's built-in functionality, or through an extension? Is there a way to do this using the R extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straightforward to do it entirely in NetLogo if you want. The reproducible code below shows how you can use `first`, `lput` and `but-first` to take (in this example, print) the first value of the list and then append it to the end of the list:

```
globals [
  lambda-values
]

to setup
  set lambda-values [1 2 3 4 5]
end

to go
  print first lambda-values
  set lambda-values lput (first lambda-values) lambda-values
  set lambda-values but-first lambda-values
  
  tick
end
```

To put this in your example, it would be:

```
to recruit-spores

  let current-lambda first lambda-values
  set lambda-values lput current-lambda lambda-values
  set lambda-values but-first lambda-values

  ask turtles with [color = red] [
    hatch-spores random-poisson current-lambda [
      set shape "dot"
      set size 0.01
      set color orange
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ]
  ] 
end
```

Alternatively, you can use `remainder` or `mod`, in combination with the current value of `ticks`, to find out the position of the item that needs to be extracted from the list (you can extract it using `item`). This solution might be in some way less preferable than the previous one, as it is ticks-dependant (as opposed to the previous one).

Another approach: implement a counter variable that is incremented each time that you use a value from `lambda-values` and that indicates the position of the next item you want to extract, and that is reset to 0 when it reaches the end of the list. This latest solution might be the least preferable because it requires you to create a global variable for the counter.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! I think the `remainder` / `mod` method might be what I'm looking for. How might I use that to find the current tick value? If I have lambda-values defined as a global variable, I'm thinking I could write something like `let current-lambda item [something that indexes ticks here] lambda_values` in the procedure block?